# Sending Input Value to java Class

Tags: java, android, class, input, parameters

This is my class.

```
package com.example.ali.pdftoepub;

import android.util.Log;

import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.Vector;

public class SemTextExtractionStrategy implements TextExtractionStrategy {

    private String text;

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {
    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        text = renderInfo.getFont().getPostscriptFontName();

        }
    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {
    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getResultantText() {

        return text;
    }
}
```

This is my using way of my class.

```
String text =  PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1, semTextExtractionStrategy)
```

Can i send an integer parameter to this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an attribute to your class and set it before passing the semTextExtractionStrategy object to the PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage.

Something like:

```
public class SemTextExtractionStrategy implements TextExtractionStrategy
{
private String text;
private int myInt;
public void setMyInt(int i){
 this.myInt = i;
}
......
```

The you can use myInt in the inner methods.

```
semTextExtractionStrategy.setMyInt(5);
String text =  PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1, semTextExtractionStrategy)
```